# Mailmerge Does Not Display Zip Correctly

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

I have a Microsoft Word mail-merge where I have to select between two different addresses to print. Input source is an Excel spreadsheet. The spreadsheet has two sets of addresses. The first set is the home address. The second set is the mailing address. The home address is always filled in. The mailing address only contains data if the the person wants mail sent somewhere other than the home address, like a PO Box. I have an if statement set up to choose which set of addresses to print. It works with the exception that when printing the mail address zip code it prints it as a date. For example, Zip code 11575 prints as 9/9/1931. The following is  the code.

```
{ if { MERGEFIELD Mail_Addr1 } = "" "{ADDRESSBLOCK \f "<<_FIRST0_>><< _LAST0_>><< _SUFFIX0_>>
<<_COMPANY_ 
>><<_STREET1_ 
>><<_STREET2_ 
>><<_CITY_>><<, _STATE_>><< _POSTAL_>><< 
_COUNTRY_>>" \l 1033 \c 2 \e "United States" \d }" "{ MERGEFIELD FirstName }{ MERGEFIELD LastName } 
{ MERGEFIELD Mail_Addr1 }
{ MERGEFIELD Mail_Addr2 \f "
"} {MERGEFIELD Mail_City }, { MERGEFIELD Mail_State }{MERGEFIELD Mail_Zip }"}
```

I have tried formatting the Mail_Zip column as general, number, text, and even put a ' in front of the zip code to force it to text and the zip code did not print properly.

I tried adding the \# switch with arguments of 00000, '00000', "00000" and all it printed was five zeroes.

How do I get the zip code to print properly?

Comment: See *Mailmerge Data Format Problems* in the **Mailmerge Tips & Tricks** thread at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

Answer (score 0):

Well it gets stranger. Trying to eliminate data entry errors I retyped the zip code. Now with no switches it prints 12:00:00 AM. With the \# "00000" switch it prints 00012.

As a test I added { MERGEFIELD Zip } (the home address zip) on its own line and it displays correctly.

Can't figure out why Mail_Zip is different.

Update 1: I closed and re-opened the word doc, as I did a dozen times yesterday, and now it is working.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

### Word does not care about formatting done in Excel and ignores it.

Try formatting your field in Word.

```
{MERGEFIELD Mail_Zip \# "00000" }
```

See Word MVP Graham Mayor's work on [formatting switches for fields](http://www.gmayor.com/formatting_word_fields.htm).

Comment: As stated in my original post I tried that and all it printed was 00000,

Comment: Thank you for your response.